# How much of my (first) novel should be completed before trying to find a publisher?

Tags: publishing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I shop an unfinished novel?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/2336/can-i-shop-an-unfinished-novel)

I assumed this question had already been answered but I found *nothing* regarding it.

I've heard that before publishing your first novel, you need to have it completed or you won't get any responses. If you don't already have a completed and revised copy (obviously not perfect for release but at least showing some touching up), they won't trust that you can finish the work and won't even look at your work.

Is this true? False?

What else should I know?

Thanks!